# One liner with nested if/else conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

Real python noob here, and I'm a bit puzzled by looking at the result of this nested if/else one-liner:

```
>>> num_arr = [5, 10, 15]
>>> [i**2 if i == 10 else i-5 if i < 7 else i+5 for i in num_arr]
[0, 100, 20]
```

Shouldn't the result be `[0, 15, 20]` since 10 is greater than 7?

Comment: Tests are evaluated L-R so `i==10` gets tested before `i < 7`

Comment: You can fix that with a pair of parentheses: `[(i**2 if i == 10 else i-5) if i < 7 else i+5 for i in num_arr]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, the "correct" version (note the parentheses) is:

```
[(i**2 if i == 10 else i-5) if i < 7 else i+5 for i in num_arr]
```

Your "problem" stems from the chaining of your `if` statements, which execute in the English reading order (left to right). So it reads like this:

```
[i**2 if i == 10 else (i-5 if i < 7 else i+5) for i in num_arr]
```

- where `i=5`, `i != 10` in the "first expression", so you move to `else`; where `i < 7` so you get `i-5`, or `0`
- where `i=10`, `i == 10` so you get `i**2`, or `100`
- where `i=15`, `i != 10` so you move to `else`, where `i` is *not* less than `7`, so you get `i+5`, or `20`

[From the documentation:](https://docs.python.org/3.1/whatsnew/2.0.html#list-comprehensions)

> To make the semantics very clear, a list comprehension is equivalent to the following Python code:
>
> ```
> for expr1 in sequence1:
>     for expr2 in sequence2:
>     ...
>         for exprN in sequenceN:
>              if (condition):
>                   # Append the value of
>                   # the expression to the
>                   # resulting list.
> ```

That means yours looks like:

```
[[expr1] if [condition] else [[expr2] if [condition] else [expr3]] for ...]
```

Comment: Putting parentheses in doesn't make any sense, if `i < 7` then `i == 10` cannot possibly be true. The *only* reasonable behaviour of the code is to produce `[0, 100, 20]`

Comment: @Nick : Yes, I put "correct" in quotations for a reason.. "correct" meaning "yields the desired output" of `[0, 15, 20]`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the expanded version of the one liner:

```
for i in num_arr:
    if i == 10:
        i ** 2
    else:
        if i < 7:
            i - 5
        else:
            i + 5
```

The one-liner if statement is basically: `[action] if [condition] else [action]`. In other words, do this if said condition is met. Otherwise, do this action.

It's a reason I don't like one-liners is because they become less Pythonic. The code above is more verbose but it's easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

The value if the condition is True is stated before the if and the value if False is after the else (see https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-308.html).

Result is i-5 for 5 because i is not 10 but it is < 7

Result is i ** 2 for 10 because i == 10

Result is i + 5 for 15 because i is not 10 and it is not < 7

Hence [0, 100, 20]